# How do you zoom out in the SceneKit user interface?

Tags: scenekit

It seems so simple, but I just can't zoom out! Everything online with these search terms is about coding the effects in the app. My issue is not in the app; I just want to evaluate and edit all of the objects in a SceneKit scene in the user interface, and add cameras and lights when I can see the whole scene. But, I can't zoom out far enough to see all of the objects.

Comment: Hold down alt and use the scroll wheel.

Comment: (thx) I don't have a scroll wheel. Holding option and scrolling with the mouse zooms the entire OS screen, so it doesn't show more of the nodes.

Comment: If option (alt) on the scroll wheel zooms the whole screen, go to `System Preferences > Accessibility > Zoom` and check what modifier key you have set. Mine is set to control so it doesn't conflict.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks much - can you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold down `option` and use the scroll wheel on the mouse to zoom in the SceneKit editor.

Make sure you don't have any conflicting settings, for instance Accessibility Zoom in System Preferences.

Comment: Mac Catalyst not working , do you have any idea how to do it ?